# Boolean modifier: Carve vs BMesh solver

Tags: modifiers

What is the difference between the solver for the Boolean operator.
It is obvious that `Carve` and `BMesh` give different result, but I'm unclear on when I should use which one?

The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) says: 'TODO' which isn't all too helpful.

Can anyone shed any light on their specifics and appropriate use-cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Carve* booleans are used in Blender for a long time. This library has it's own limitations and cases when it will fail and produce incorrect results. It is also very slow.

*Bmesh* booleans is the new implementation aiming at being a faster solver (really shows on high-dense geometries). So far it also has limitations, but devs are working on it to resolve any bugs. You can trace the progress here:

[BMesh booleans (track todo's)](https://developer.blender.org/T47030)

Bmesh might handle some cases better than Carve and vice-versa. It depends on the geometry and those cases are hard to generalize. Bmesh should be faster than Carve. You should avoid [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry) for both.

In time Bmesh booleans might (hopefully will) fully replace Carve booleans.

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick note that Blender has now removed the Carve boolean library. The last release containing Carve is 2.79. Further information can be found here: https://developer.blender.org/D3050