# Why does such a simple boolean operation result in hollow mesh?

Tags: modifiers

Create a default cube. Create default cylinder.Rotate cylinder 90 degrees and scale length. Place cylinder's origin at the surface of the cube. Use difference boolean.

This is about as simple of a boolean operation as you can get, using two of the simplest default shapes, and it just randomly does not work. Sure, if you tweak the rotation of the cylinder or offset its position ever so slightly, tada it works. This is beyond frustrating.[image]

Comment: Might be related to this bug: https://developer.blender.org/T37659   You mention it resolves if you move one of the objects slightly, which sounds like the workaround in the bug report.

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5140/49532

Comment: @zippy According to this Blender no longer uses that library. Maybe the information is incorrect. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/100713/74766

Comment: This mentions that the current BMesh boolean code has a limitation with touching edges, which appears to be the issue with my example. How annoying. https://developer.blender.org/D3050

Comment: Yeah, boolean has always been a disappointment for me too.

Comment: I seem to recall encountering the "touching edges" issue even when using booleans in other 3D programs. I'm not sure this is a Blender specific thing.